# How to change xib file's path?

Tags: iphone, ios, location, xcode4.2, filepath

When you move a project folder, the problem was files for localization link is broken.
[image]

I tried to change link broken file's Full Path, but I can't.

This is correct case.:

[image]

This image is that file link is broken.
This file's path is set "Absolute path". And I can change this path.

[image]

Is there any way to change? ^ ^

Answer (score 2):

Honestly, the easiest thing to do is delete the red unlinked files and re-drag in the correct files into the project in Xcode. Otherwise, you're typing in long links. This is probably not best practice, but works fine for me.